# Order grid filter on the basic of custom attribute

Tags: magento2, filter

This lines of code return the order collection, but I don't known which hierarchy of file. Where I can put this lines of code?
What I am should use a **plugin, preference** or else?   and how tom implement in my custom module?

```
   $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
    foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
        $getid =  $orderDatamodel1->getData('increment_id');
        $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($getid);
        $getorderdata = $orderData->getData();
        $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($orderItems as $orderItems){
           echo '</pre>', var_dump($orderItems->getData()),'</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use that in a model or in a controller

Comment: i need any observer or plugin.
how can use any event when load order grid?